# Trying to use pip unsinstall using subprocess module in python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, subprocess

I am trying to uninstall any_repo but I am not getting any

1.any_repo='libclang-py3'

2. uninstall_dependency=subprocess.Popen(["python3","-m","pip","uninstall",'%s'%libclang_repo],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
3. (output,err)=uninstall_dependency.communicate(input='y',timeout=20)
4. print("Output is %s and Error is %s"%(output,err))

The line 2 requires a prompt of y/n. the line 3 is supposed to provide the value as 'y' but it is not giving. I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pip uninstall -h | grep -A1 yes
  -y, --yes                   Don't ask for confirmation of uninstall
                              deletions.
```

That is, run `pip uninstall -y` (or `pip3 uninstall -y` or `python -m pip uninstall -y`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to the process *stdin*, you need to use a pipe to the stdin:
`uninstall_dependency=subprocess.Popen(["python3","-m","pip","uninstall",'%s'%libclang_repo],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`